# How to specify starting value of <meter> tag not from zero?

Tags: html, meter

Suppose, I want to specify (highlight) the range of meter tag from 0.4 to 0.6 values. How can I do that?

```html
<meter max="0.6" min="0.4"></meter>
```

I want to do something like this:

Meter with range
[image]

Comment: [Meter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter) or [input type Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) do not seem to support that. Instead try and find a range widget or a two-thumb range widget and remove the thumbs

Answer (score 0):

Use the meter element to display a scalar value within a given range (a gauge):

```html
<meter value="0.4" min="0.2" ax="0.6">0.4 out of 0.6</meter>
```

[image]

Comment: That is not what was asked